# Why is apt dist-upgrade downloading 2 versions of linux kernel? How to prevent it?

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, updates, xorg

In on 18.04, I've updated to linux kernel 5 using `sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04`

Now, when do a `apt-get dist-upgrade` It downloads both kernel 4.15.0-X & 5.0.0-X but ends up using 5.0.0-X. Now how do I prevent `dist-upgrade` to download `4.15.0-x`? is it even required?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by removing kernel meta-packages

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
```

Now you'll get only HWE kernels.

Those packages pull inintial Ubuntu 18.04 4.15.x kernels, but you have

```
linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04
```

that pull current hwe kernels.

You can also remove the 4.15 kernel image and headers if you are sure you don't need them any more.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt purge linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
```

if you want get rid of 4.15 kernel-line.

this meta-package draw linux-image-generic and linux-headers-generic and that points to kernel line 4.15

Comment: That won't work.

Comment: yes, I forgot the other 2 metapackages.

Comment: `linux-generic` will be removed by either of the other.